# Алгоритмы решения задачи классификации

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Дали такое задание на собеседовании, в качестве ДЗ, вакансия IT-аналитик. Просмотреть решения можно снизу в комментариях.

1-я половина столбцов
[image: 1-я половина столбцов]

2-я половина (вся excel таблица размером 5658 х 58)
[image: 2-я половина]

Непосредственно, задание:
[image: Непосредственно, задание]

ссылка на файл с заданием и данными:  http://yadi.sk/i/gDtn6k03w3cqWw

Comment: Немного дурацкая формулировка задания. Это задача регрессии, т.к. найти надо две суммы - зачем они называют это классификацией? Чтобы запутать?

Comment: Можете выложить данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: да, конечно
вот ссылка: https://yadi.sk/i/gDtn6k03w3cqWw

Comment: На 2м листе указано "Использовать XGBoost". Это библиотека, для языка R. Это вовсе не обязательно. Я могу пользоваться только пайтоном, по машинному обучению мало что знаю, начал читать книгу "Андреас Мюллер. Введение в машинное обучение с помощью Python".  Буду вам признателен, за любую информацию по решению.

Comment: Я с XGBoost не работал. Я бы использовал Keras/Tensorflow/PyTorch ну или в самом простом случае Sklearn. Попробую построить модель когда будет больше свободного времени

Comment: а о каком 'gini' идет речь? и что значит 'target'? У меня дедлайн - 3е число. Буду разбираться в общем, обязательно пишите, по возможности)

Comment: По поводу Gini - если хотите работать аналитиком, то вам просто необходимо научиться пользоваться поисковиками ;) “Target” в машинном обучении это то что мы предсказываем

Comment: Понял. Извиняюсь за некомпетентность. Сегодня только собеседование было, толком еще ни в чем не успел разобраться. До этого никогда не занимался скоринговыми моделями.

Comment: Советую вам начать с подготовки данных - напишите код для чтения, нормализации (StandardScaler / MinMaxScaler) и очистки (от NaN) данных и приведите его в вопросе. Можно воспользоваться Pandas для чтения и Sklearn для нормализации

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#impute

Comment: Таблицу нормализовал, код привел в вопросе. Дальше нужно воспользоваться именно логистической регрессией, из модуля sklearn? Почему не другим алгоритмом? Иправильно ли, что я Nan заменил на медианы?

Comment: `"Сумма оплат и Сумма выдач - данные для выбора target'` - можно понять по-разному.  Вы можете уточнить что именно нужно предсказывать? Все три столбца или только `"Риск"` - если только "Риск", то эта задача классификации, но тогда непонятно для чего даны столбцы `Сумма оплат` и `Сумма выдач`...

Comment: "логистическая регрессия" - несмотря на присутствие слова "регрессия" является задачей классификации

Comment: я не понял ваш ответ... предсказываем только "Риск" или все три столбца?

Comment: Если предсказываем только "Риск", то у меня получилось постороить модель с точностью предсказаний ~98%. С предсказанием сумм все гораздо хуже

Comment: Да, предугадывать нужно только Риск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Также можно воспользоваться более глубокими сверточными нейронными сетями (Convolutional Neural Networks). После 100 эпох обучения эта модель показала лучший результат - 97.17% правильных предсказаний на незнакомой выборке данных:

```
In [34]: clf.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
566/566 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step
Out[34]: [0.08433653733465991, 0.9717314487632509]

Normalized confusion matrix
[[0.967 0.033]
 [0.014 0.986]]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:

```
def _conv1d(model, name_suffix=1, filters=32, kernel_size=(3),
            padding='same', use_bias=True, max_pool_size=None,
            **kwargs):
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=filters,
                     kernel_size=kernel_size,
                     padding=padding,
                     use_bias=use_bias,
                     name=f'conv_{name_suffix}',
                     **kwargs))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name=f'norm_{name_suffix}'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    if max_pool_size is not None:
        model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=max_pool_size))
    return model


def train_CNN_clf(X, Y, validation_split=0.1, input_shape=(49,1),
                  model_fn=None, lr=0.01,
                  epochs=100, batch_size=32,
                  patience=30, verbose=1):
    # building a prediction model
    model = Sequential(name='CNN')
    model = _conv1d(model, 1, 32, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=3,
                        input_shape=input_shape)
    model = _conv1d(model, 2, 64, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=3)
    model = _conv1d(model, 3, 128, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=None)
    model = _conv1d(model, 4, 64, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=None)
    model = _conv1d(model, 5, 128, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=3)
    model = _conv1d(model, 6, 256, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=None)
    model = _conv1d(model, 7, 64, 5, 'same', max_pool_size=None)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_8'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_9'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='dense_out'))
    model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=lr), loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    print(model.summary())
    # Keras callbacks...
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, mode='auto',
                               patience=min(patience, epochs), verbose=1)
    if model_fn is None:
        model_fn = str(Path(data_fn).parent / 'model_cnn.h5')
    chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(str(model_fn), 
                            monitor='val_acc', 
                            verbose=1, 
                            save_best_only=True, 
                            mode='auto')
    # training the model
    clf_hist = model.fit(X, Y,
                         validation_split=validation_split,
                         epochs=epochs,
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         callbacks=[early_stop, chkpt])
    return load_model(model_fn)

def main():
    work_dir = Path(r'D:\Work\ML\Classification\SO.885958-Keras_classification')
    data_fn = work_dir / 'ZADANIE.xlsx'
    model_fn = work_dir / 'model_cnn.h5'
    EPOCHS = 50
    BATCH_SIZE = 64

    # get and normalize data
    X, Y = get_data(data_fn)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)


    clf = train_CNN_clf(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1,
                        model_fn=model_fn, lr=0.05,
                        epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)
    Y_pred = clf.predict_classes(X_test).ravel()

    # Compute confusion matrix
    class_names = ['OK', 'RISK']
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

    # Plot normalized confusion matrix
    plt.figure()
    plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=True,
                      title='Normalized confusion matrix')
    plt.savefig(str(Path(data_fn).parent / 'confusion_matrix_CNN.png'))
    #plt.show()

    #loss, acc = clf.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
```

PS остальные функции такие же как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/886379/211923).

Answer (score 1):

Я исходил из того, что это задача классификации и предсказывать надо последний столбец "Риск".

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
Normalized confusion matrix
[[0.972 0.028]
 [0.047 0.953]]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import os
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
try:
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer as Imputer
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.preprocessing.imputation import Imputer
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import Adam, Nadam
from keras.regularizers import l1, l2
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

######################

def get_data(filename, target_col_name='Риск', impute=True, normalize=True):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=0)
    X, Y = df.iloc[:, :54], df[target_col_name]
    # get rid of columns with a single unique value (all rows have the same value)
    X = X.loc[:, X.nunique() > 1]
    # get list of binary and numeric columns
    bin_cols = X.columns[X.nunique() == 2]
    num_cols = X.columns.difference(bin_cols)
    if impute:
        # imputing missing data (NaN's)
        imp = Imputer()
        X = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(X), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)
    if normalize:
        # normalizing data
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        X[num_cols] = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X[num_cols]),
                                   columns=num_cols, index=X.index)
    return X, Y


def train_classifier(X, Y, validation_split=0.1, model_fn=None, lr=0.01,
                     epochs=100, batch_size=32,
                     patience=30, verbose=1):
    # building a prediction model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(49,), name='dense_1'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='norm_1'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='norm_2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_3'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='norm_3'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense_4'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(name='norm_4'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='dense_out'))
    model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(lr=lr), loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    # Keras callbacks...
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, mode='auto',
                               patience=min(patience, epochs), verbose=1)
    if model_fn is None:
        model_fn = str(Path(data_fn).parent / 'risk_clf.h5')
    chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(str(model_fn), 
                            monitor='val_acc', 
                            verbose=1, 
                            save_best_only=True, 
                            mode='auto')
    # training the model
    clf_hist = model.fit(X, Y,
                         validation_split=validation_split,
                         epochs=epochs,
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         callbacks=[early_stop, chkpt])

    return load_model(model_fn)


def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    (c) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py
    """
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.3f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.tight_layout()

#############################################################################

def main():
    work_dir = Path(r'D:\Work\ML\Classification\SO.885958-Keras_classification')
    data_fn = work_dir / 'ZADANIE.xlsx'
    clf_model_fn = work_dir / 'model.h5'
    EPOCHS = 200
    BATCH_SIZE = 32

    # get and normalize data
    X, Y = get_data(data_fn)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)


    clf = train_classifier(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1,
                           model_fn=clf_model_fn, lr=0.05,
                           epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)
    Y_pred = clf.predict_classes(X_test).ravel()

    # Compute confusion matrix
    class_names = ['OK', 'RISK']
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

    # Plot normalized confusion matrix
    plt.figure()
    plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=True,
                      title='Normalized confusion matrix')
    plt.savefig(str(Path(data_fn).parent / 'confusion_matrix.png'))
    #plt.show()

    #loss, acc = clf.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

#############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Завтра обязательно посмотрю, отпишусь

Comment: Если честно, пока только сумел разобрать вашу функцию get_data.
Собственно, я что-то отдаленно напоминающее потому что и сам сделал. Считывание, замена Nan, нормализация, и деление на target и feautures. Остальное пока темный лес

Comment: @Ste_kd, если вы никогда не сталкивались с задачами машинного обучения и нейронными сетями, то вам, честно говоря, трудно будет все это за несколько дней осилить...

Comment: я добавил свое решение (не без вашей помощи :) ), оцените?

Comment: @Ste_kd, по-моему у вас очень неплохо получается. Можно оформить ваш вариант решения как ответ...

Comment: Пока что еще не готово, пытаюсь разобраться как посчитать индекс Джини и график соответствующий построить

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение, при построении модели признаки 1,3,4,5,6 отбрасывал. Некоторые "импорты" в этом коде не используются, т.к. есть еще одна функция для подсчета параметров, которую я не выложил.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer as Imputer
    from sklearn import ensemble
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
    from scipy.integrate import quad
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve
    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    plt.style.use('ggplot')


def plotting_Gini(targetcolumn, predictcolumn):
    actual = list(targetcolumn.values)
    predict = list(predictcolumn.values)
    data = zip(actual, predict)
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[1], reverse=True)
    sorted_actual = [d[0] for d in sorted_data]

    cumulative_actual = np.cumsum(sorted_actual) / sum(actual)
    cumulative_index = np.arange(1, len(cumulative_actual) + 1) / len(predict)
    cumulative_actual_perfect = np.cumsum(sorted(actual, reverse=True)) / sum(actual)

    aucroc = roc_auc_score(actual, predict)
    gini = 2 * roc_auc_score(actual, predict) - 1
    fpr, tpr, t = roc_curve(actual, predict)
    x_values = [0] + list(cumulative_index)
    y_values = [0] + list(cumulative_actual)
    y_values_perfect = [0] + list(cumulative_actual_perfect)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharey=True, figsize=(18, 6))
    fig.suptitle(f'Gini = {gini}\n\n', fontsize=26, fontweight='bold')

    f1, f2 = interp1d(x_values, y_values), interp1d(x_values, y_values_perfect)
    S_pred = quad(f1, 0, 1, points=x_values, limit=len(x_values))[0] - 0.5
    S_actual = quad(f2, 0, 1, points=x_values, limit=len(x_values))[0] - 0.5

    ax[0].plot([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), lw=2, color='red')
    ax[0].plot([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), lw=2, color='red')
    ax[0].fill_between([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), color='red', alpha=0.1)
    ax[0].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(aucroc), fontsize=28)
    ax[1].plot(x_values, y_values, lw=2, color='blue')
    ax[1].fill_between(x_values, x_values, y_values, color='blue', alpha=0.1)
    ax[1].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(S_pred), fontsize=28)
    ax[2].plot(x_values, y_values_perfect, lw=2, color='green')
    ax[2].fill_between(x_values, x_values, y_values_perfect, color='green', alpha=0.1)
    ax[2].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(S_actual), fontsize=28)

    ax[0].set(title='ROC-AUC Baseline', xlabel='False Positive Rate',
              ylabel='True Positive Rate', xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
    ax[1].set(title='Gini Baseline')
    ax[2].set(title='Gini Perfect')
    for i in range(1, 3):
        ax[i].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='black')
        ax[i].set(xlabel='Share of clients', ylabel='True Positive Rate', xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
    plt.show()


def plotting_feature_priority(X, model, n=3):
    importances = model.feature_importances_
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
    feature_names = X.columns
    d_first = X.shape[1]
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.title("Значимость признаков")
    plt.bar(range(d_first), importances[indices[:d_first]], align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(d_first), np.array(feature_names)[indices[:d_first]], rotation=90)
    plt.xlim([-1, d_first])
    best_features = indices[:n]
    best_features_names = feature_names[best_features]
    print(f'Первые {n} значимых признаков {list(best_features_names)} из {d_first} ')
    plt.show()


def normalize_delete_Nans(features, target, impute=True, normalize=True):
    """Функция удаления Nan's и нормализация значений"""
    X, y = features, target
    # избавляемся от строк имеющих одинаковое значение
    # альтернативный вариант:
    # (.nunique() - Возвращает число уникальных значений в столбце)
    # notsamevls = [clmn for clmn in X.columns if X[clmn].nunique() > 1]
    # X = X[notsamevls]
    X = X.loc[:, X.nunique() > 1]
    # получаем список бинарных и числовых столбцов
    bin_cols = X.columns[X.nunique() == 2]
    num_cols = X.columns.difference(bin_cols)
    if impute:
        imp = Imputer()
        # избавление от NaN's
        # альтернативные варианты:
        # X = X.fillna(X.median(axis=0), axis=0) # Замена медианами
        # X.fillna(-999, inplace=True) # Замена числом -999
        X = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(X), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)
    if normalize:
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        # "сглаживание", нормализация данных
        # альтернативный вариант:
        # (каждый количественный признак приводится к нулевому среднему и единичному среднеквадратичному отклонению)
        # X[num_cols] = (X[num_cols] - X[num_cols].mean()) / X[num_cols].std()
        X[num_cols] = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X[num_cols]), columns=num_cols, index=X.index)
    return X, y


def create_and_learn_rf_classifier(X, y, n=1, inf=True):
    '''Создание и обучение классификатора RF, возвращает модель и предсказанный результат по всем признакам,
    n - параметр проставления балла 0 - в обратном порядке '''
    # разбиение выборки на учебную и тестовую
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
    # создаю модель и обучаю
    rf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                                         max_depth=30, max_features=5, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                         min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                                         min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                                         min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=250, n_jobs=-1,
                                         oob_score=True, random_state=42, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    prediction = rf.predict_proba(X)[:, n]

    if inf:
        err_test = np.mean(y_test != rf.predict(X_test))
        print(f'Средняя доля верных ответов: {100 - err_test * 100}%')
        print(f'Минимальное предсказанное значение: {min(prediction)}, максимальное: {max(prediction)}')

    return rf, prediction

if __name__ == "__main__":
    drctry = 'C:\\Users\\Stepan\\Downloads\\ZADANIE.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(drctry)  # ,index_col=0 делает значениями индексов в таблице df - 1й столбец
    target = df['Риск']  # цель
    features = df[df.columns[2:55]]  # признаки

    X, y = normalize_delete_Nans(features, target)
    #print(X.head())

    model, result = create_and_learn_rf_classifier(X, y, 0)

    # график приоритетов признаков и индекса Джини
    plotting_feature_priority(X, model, 10)
    plotting_Gini(y, pd.Series(create_and_learn_rf_classifier(X, y, 1, inf=False)[1], index=X.index))

    # создаю столбец со скоринговым баллом и записываю в файл
    df["Score"] = pd.DataFrame(np.array(result), index=X.index)
    #print(df["Score"].value_counts())
    df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Stepan\\Downloads\\res.xlsx')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]