# Фильтр по датам, groupby и сумма строк (Pandas, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, big-data

```
id          date    money          
42662   29.01.2011  5.0
42662   27.02.2011  80.0
42662   28.07.2011  80.0
42662   27.07.2011  80.0
42662   26.07.2011  80.0
42662   25.07.2011  80.0
42662   24.07.2011  80.0
42662   23.07.2011  80.0
42662   22.07.2011  80.0
42662   21.07.2011  80.0
42662   20.07.2011  80.0
42662   19.07.2011  80.0
42662   18.07.2011  80.0
42662   17.07.2011  80.0
42662   16.07.2011  80.0
42662   15.07.2011  80.0
42662   14.07.2011  80.0
42662   13.07.2011  80.0
42662   12.07.2011  80.0
42662   11.07.2011  80.0
42662   10.07.2011  80.0
42662   09.07.2011  80.0
42662   08.07.2011  80.0
42662   07.07.2011  80.0
42662   06.07.2011  80.0
42662   05.07.2011  80.0
42662   04.07.2011  80.0
42662   03.07.2011  80.0
42662   02.07.2011  80.0
42662   24.06.2011  0.0
42661   05.07.2011  5.0
42661   05.07.2011  80.0
42661   04.07.2011  80.0
42661   24.06.2011  5.0
```

Например, есть такой dataframe и в нем 3 столбца. Надо их "схлопнуть" по ID, т.е. узнать сумму всех строк столбца Money по каждому ID. При этом в каждом ID строки надо еще отфильтровать по дате, т.е. надо найти сумму ТОЛЬКО по тем строкам, у которых, дата не превышает самую раннюю дату по ID + 130 дней. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, очень требуется помощь. Как это можно реализовать?

В результате преобразований таблицы, из примера выше, должно получиться:

```
id      money
42662    85
42661    170
```

В ID 42662 были отброшены все строки при суммировании, у которых дата была больше, чем

"29.01.2011 + 130 дней" --> "08.06.2011"

Comment: можете показать что должно получиться в результате (из приведенного в вопросе DF)?

Comment: Что такое? Увидел, ваш ответ, с утра проверю) ничего в голову не лезет, как совершить данное преобразование

Comment: Не совсем понял, к чему вы это?) Все  преобразования которые нужно совершить, я знаю как делать, но по отдельности, а чтобы это все одновременно было, пока не понимаю как (кстати я устроился на ту работу) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885958/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Очисткой данных сейчас занимаюсь вот

Comment: Поздравляю с новой работой! :)

Comment: Спасибо) Ждите примерно еще с десяток моих вопросов по Pandas и Scikit learn на stack overflow))

Comment: Похоже вы результирующий DF неправильно посчитали...

Comment: @Ste_kd уж лучше спрашивать про  CNTK  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DF отсортрованный по `id` и по `date`:

```
In [68]: df.sort_values(['id','date'])
Out[68]:
       id       date  money
32  42661 2011-04-07   80.0   # min date for id==42661:  2011-04-07
30  42661 2011-05-07    5.0
31  42661 2011-05-07   80.0
33  42661 2011-06-24    5.0
0   42662 2011-01-29    5.0   # min date for id==42662:  2011-01-29
28  42662 2011-02-07   80.0
1   42662 2011-02-27   80.0
27  42662 2011-03-07   80.0
26  42662 2011-04-07   80.0
25  42662 2011-05-07   80.0
24  42662 2011-06-07   80.0
29  42662 2011-06-24    0.0
23  42662 2011-07-07   80.0
17  42662 2011-07-13   80.0
16  42662 2011-07-14   80.0
15  42662 2011-07-15   80.0
14  42662 2011-07-16   80.0
13  42662 2011-07-17   80.0
12  42662 2011-07-18   80.0
11  42662 2011-07-19   80.0
10  42662 2011-07-20   80.0
9   42662 2011-07-21   80.0
8   42662 2011-07-22   80.0
7   42662 2011-07-23   80.0
6   42662 2011-07-24   80.0
5   42662 2011-07-25   80.0
4   42662 2011-07-26   80.0
3   42662 2011-07-27   80.0
2   42662 2011-07-28   80.0
22  42662 2011-08-07   80.0
21  42662 2011-09-07   80.0
20  42662 2011-10-07   80.0
19  42662 2011-11-07   80.0
18  42662 2011-12-07   80.0
```

---

Решение:

```
In [69]: df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['date'] <= x['date'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(130), 'money'].sum())
Out[69]:
id
42661    170.0
42662    485.0
dtype: float64
```

Проверка:

```
In [71]: dmax1 = df.loc[df['id']==42661, 'date'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(130)

In [72]: dmax2 = df.loc[df['id']==42662, 'date'].min() + pd.offsets.Day(130)

In [73]: dmax1
Out[73]: Timestamp('2011-08-15 00:00:00')

In [74]: dmax2
Out[74]: Timestamp('2011-06-08 00:00:00')

In [75]: df.loc[(df['id']==42661) & (df['date'] <= dmax1)]
Out[75]:
       id       date  money
30  42661 2011-05-07    5.0
31  42661 2011-05-07   80.0
32  42661 2011-04-07   80.0
33  42661 2011-06-24    5.0

In [76]: df.loc[(df['id']==42661) & (df['date'] <= dmax1), 'money'].sum()
Out[76]: 170.0

In [77]: df.loc[(df['id']==42662) & (df['date'] <= dmax2)]
Out[77]:
       id       date  money
0   42662 2011-01-29    5.0
1   42662 2011-02-27   80.0
24  42662 2011-06-07   80.0
25  42662 2011-05-07   80.0
26  42662 2011-04-07   80.0
27  42662 2011-03-07   80.0
28  42662 2011-02-07   80.0

In [78]: df.loc[(df['id']==42662) & (df['date'] <= dmax2), 'money'].sum()
Out[78]: 485.0
```