# Фильтр по датам, groupby и сумма строк (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

(задавал уже такой вопрос по Pandas в Python, на него дали ответ:

[Фильтр по датам, groupby и сумма строк (Pandas, Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901127/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-groupby-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA)

теперь интересует как это можно сделать запросом на MS SQL сервер)

```
id          date    money          
42662   29.01.2011  5.0
42662   27.02.2011  80.0
42662   28.07.2011  80.0
42662   27.07.2011  80.0
42662   26.07.2011  80.0
42662   25.07.2011  80.0
42662   24.07.2011  80.0
42662   23.07.2011  80.0
42662   22.07.2011  80.0
42662   21.07.2011  80.0
42662   20.07.2011  80.0
42662   19.07.2011  80.0
42662   18.07.2011  80.0
42662   17.07.2011  80.0
42662   16.07.2011  80.0
42662   15.07.2011  80.0
42662   14.07.2011  80.0
42662   13.07.2011  80.0
42662   12.07.2011  80.0
42662   11.07.2011  80.0
42662   10.07.2011  80.0
42662   09.07.2011  80.0
42662   08.07.2011  80.0
42662   07.07.2011  80.0
42662   06.07.2011  80.0
42662   05.07.2011  80.0
42662   04.07.2011  80.0
42662   03.07.2011  80.0
42662   02.07.2011  80.0
42662   24.06.2011  0.0
42661   05.07.2011  5.0
42661   05.07.2011  80.0
42661   04.07.2011  80.0
42661   24.06.2011  5.0
```

Например, есть такая таблица, с названием `Paytab`, и в ней 3 столбца. Надо их "схлопнуть" по `ID`, т.е. узнать сумму всех строк столбца `Money` по каждому `ID`. При этом в каждом ID строки надо еще отфильтровать по дате, т.е. надо найти сумму ТОЛЬКО по тем строкам, у которых, дата не превышает самую раннюю дату по ID + 130 дней. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, очень требуется помощь. Как это можно реализовать?

Результатом запроса должна получиться такая таблица:

```
id      money
42662    85
42661    170
```

В ID 42662 были отброшены все строки при суммировании, у которых дата была больше, чем

"29.01.2011 + 130 дней" --> "08.06.2011"

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: Вопрос не о том как сгруппировать id и найти сумму по money. Сумма должна быть посчитана за 130 дней от минимальной даты. У каждого ID своя минимальная дата. И так по каждому ID.

Comment: по моему как раз в том как сгруппировать id и найти сумму по money, а @Mike Вам дал правильную наводку

Comment: @Ste_kd Не внимательно прочитал вопрос. Да, надо сначала получить минимальную дату а потом уже обернуть внешним запросом и сделать условие по этой дате. Нужный запрос в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оконная функция `min() over()` на окне с разбивкой по id (`partition by id`) дает минимальную дату для нужного id одновременно с обычными данными из строки. Оборачиваем это в еще один запрос и сравниваем даты, как будто и сама дата и минимальная лежали таблице.

```
select id, sum(money)
  from (
    select id, date, money, min(date) over(partition by id) min_date
      from paytab
  ) x
 where date <= DATEADD(day, 130, min_date)
 group by id
```

Comment: Доступа к БД сейчас нет, не могу проверить работоспособность запроса. На сайте
 http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref  
нашел похожую таблицу, но там выдает ошибку

**Incorrect syntax near '2 day'**

Comment: @Ste_kd Ой, точно, я на postgresql проверял, а там вместо interval функция используется, поправил

Comment: Работает, большое спасибо!
)
Надо почитать про over() и DATEADD()

Comment: @Ste_kd Да, про over() точно стоит, это очень полезный функционал современных БД. Начать можно например с https://habr.com/post/268983/ (то что там postgesql не обращайте внимания, различия у оконных функций между ним и MS SQL могут быть только в некоторых особых конструкциях, которые используются раз в пятилетку)

Comment: @Mike, суть та же ;)

Comment: @Mike, суть та же ;)  +1

Answer (score 1):

как-то так :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT RES.ID,
                SUM(RES.MONEY) OVER (PARTITION BY RES.ID) RES_MONEY
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM DF
          ORDER BY ID, DATA) RES
  WHERE RES.DATA < ANY (SELECT MIN(ONE.DATA + 130) OVER (PARTITION BY RES.ID)
                          FROM DF ONE
                          WHERE ONE.ID = RES.ID)
  ORDER BY RES.ID;
```